# Getting Error: Objects are not valid as React child

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, react-component

The screenshot of issueList array element which is an object.
[image: issueList Array]

```
import React from 'react';

const IssueList = (props)=>{
    const issues = props.issueList.map((issue)=>{
        return (
            <div key={issue.id}>
                <span>
                    <p><strong>Issue Title: </strong>{issue.title}   </p>
                    <p>   <strong>Created By : </strong>{issue.user["login"]}</p>
                </span>   
                <p><strong>Assigned to: </strong>{issue.assignee}</p>
                <p><strong>Issue Description: </strong>{issue.body}</p>
            </div>
        )

    });

    return <div>{issues}</div>;
}
```

I'm trying to render a div with some info from my issueList array of objects.
Above code produces the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {login, id, node_id, avatar_url, gravatar_id, url, html_url, followers_url, following_url, gists_url, starred_url, subscriptions_url, organizations_url, repos_url, events_url, received_events_url, type, site_admin}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at IssueList.js:12)
    in div (at IssueList.js:7)
    in div (at IssueList.js:19)
```

issueList is an array of objects

Comment: One of your values is an object. We can't tell you which without seeing an example of one of your issue objects, but you need to access a nested property somewhere, like `issue.body.description` or `issue.assignee.login`

Comment: You can see the issue in your screenshot.. `issue.assignee` is an object

Comment: Thanks, @azium..was really frustrated and didn't see it.

Answer (score -1):

So you have an array of `issueList` which you want to render as a list of components (let's say `IssueList`). Assuming that your issue is set up like following

```js
issue = {
  id: "ID string",
  title: "Title",
  user: "User name",
  assignee: "Asignee name",
  body: "body string ..... "
}
```

You can first setup your `IssueList` component as following

```
const IssueList = ({ issueList }) => (
  <div>
  {
    issueList.map((issue) => (
      <div key={issue.id}>
        <span>
           <p><strong>Issue Title: </strong>{issue.title}   </p>
           <p>   <strong>Created By : </strong>{issue.user}</p>
        </span>
        <p><strong>Assigned to: </strong>{issue.assignee}</p>
        <p><strong>Issue Description: </strong>{issue.body}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  </div>
)
```

Now you can use your `IssueList` anywhere.

Comment: Do read the definition of `issue` object in my answer. Since you have not provided any definition of your `issue` objects keys and respective values. I had defined a simple `issue`. Note that all the values in my `issue` are strings and not objects.

Comment: As @azium pointed out. Your `assignee` key had an object as the value, hence you would need to access the specific key you intend to use.